# Browser handling of CSS “transparent” in gradients

Tags: css, colors, transparency, gradient

Although the CSS colors `rgba(255,255,255,0)` and `rgba(0,0,0,0)` are apparently the same, i.e. `transparent`, when being looked at as plain colors, they affect the intermediate colors in gradients:

```
linear-gradient(left center, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(255,255,255,1))
```

This yields grey semitransparent tones between the two ends.

Now my questions:

1. Do browsers select the “right” color for `transparent` automatically or is it a fixed color (most likely “black transparent” or “white transparent”)?
2. Is this different between browsers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Although [the Color module states](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparent) that `transparent` means the same as `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)`, colors behave a little differently in CSS gradients. [The Image Values module states](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#color-stop-syntax) that color stops should be interpolated in a premultiplied RGBA color space. This means that browsers are supposed to preserve the RGB colors during transitions between color-stops, and that the grey semitransparent tones shouldn't be there.
2. As of the end of October 2012, only IE10 and Opera perform this interpolation correctly, such that the grey portions aren't present and that you get a pure white 0%-to-100% alpha gradient. Other browsers display the grey portions, which is incorrect.

Comment: thanks, especially for the test! i don’t like the spec, though, css should really be more intelligent…

Comment: @BoltClock: take a look at the CSS3 Image values spec, interpolation should be done in a premultiplied color space. So the browsers are buggy, except Opera.

Comment: @Lea Verou: I finally updated my answer. It looks like the only other browser to have gotten this right is IE10. Firefox 16 still exhibits this bug, even with the unprefixed gradient functions. I haven't tested it in any nightlies.