# For a CSS3 linear gradient, does the R,G,B component change in a linear way, if we consider only one such as R?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

If I have a linear gradient defined in CSS and it appears on the screen as a gradient, does the red value change at a constant rate. (i.e. is its derivative constant for the color red for the whole length of the gradient). The same question for color components of green and blue.

The gradient may be from any color to any other color. One color may be #FF4400 and the other is #5599FF, for example (just random colors). Does the red component change linearly?

I am referring to CSS3 linear gradients, one example is here: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-linear-gradients/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the rate of change in each color component value between two color-stops in a gradient is linear. From the spec:

> At each color-stop, the line is the color of the color-stop. Between two color-stops, the line's color is linearly interpolated between the colors of the two color-stops, with the interpolation taking place in premultiplied RGBA space.

[§4.4. Gradient Color-Stops](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#color-stop-syntax) of the Image Values module contains details and examples, which I believe address your question in depth.

Some browsers currently have trouble interpolating gradient color-stops correctly, though. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241991/browser-handling-of-css-transparent-in-gradients).