# Firefox and linear-gradient as background (creates a.. border?)

Tags: css, firefox

See my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hTnD8) to see the issue. Any clue as to why this *only* happens in Firefox yet is fine in Chrome and IE?

The CSS that seems to create the issue:

```
background-color: #2A2A2A;
background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #2E2E2E 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, #2E2E2E 50%, #2E2E2E 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
background-size: 20px 20px;
```

---

Changing the definition to (no transparency):

```
background-color: #2A2A2A;
background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #2E2E2E 25%, #2A2A2A 25%, #2A2A2A 50%, #2E2E2E 50%, #2E2E2E 75%, #2A2A2A 75%, #2A2A2A);
background-size: 20px 20px;
```

seems to fix the issue, but I really would like to know *why*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked a friend who is a fellow developer and he linked me [this article](https://coderwall.com/p/tpmsta). Turns out it's an issue with `rgba` as it renders the transitions between the colors and since "transparent" is defined differently (ie. transparent black in Firefox) we get the black "border".

Another post discussing this found [here](https://coderwall.com/p/s1d2rg).

Comment: Indeed - I just finally located my answer addressing this in a little more detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241991/browser-handling-of-css-transparent-in-gradients/7242173#7242173 I should find out if recent versions of any browsers have been updated to match the spec yet. Clearly Firefox hasn't.